# Why does the Stack Overflow logo lean to the right?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, fun, logo, icons

[image]

Why does it have to overflow in a direction? And why to the right?

Who was the person behind the logo design? Maybe he/she can answer this.

Comment: I think someone forgot the `always-friday-in-iceland` tag.

Comment: [always-friday-in-iceland!!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/21413#21413)

Comment: [The logo tag!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logo)

Comment: Closed as *[We Hate Fun Here.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/)*

Answer (score 60):

That's only part of the picture.

[image]

It walks down stairs.

Comment: But how does it get out of the box?

Comment: @mmyers, magic.

Comment: @mmyers: A very strong compulsion to walk down stairs.

Comment: ...alone or in pairs... For you generationally challenged: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CM_sMM_tvX8

Comment: This is brilliant.

Comment: I had a slinky ... I straightened it. -- Egon Spengler

Comment: Let's hope the logo doesn't suffer [this fate](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V8szWccJvb4).

Comment: Over your neighbors dog.

Comment: @mmyers `.pop()` =p

Comment: Haha, I've never thought of it this way :D

Answer (score 20):

It was the result of a [design contest](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/04/logo-design-contest-winner/); the winner was [Peter Borlace](http://99designs.com/users/241303)

Comment: This sounds way too sensible to be the right answer.

Comment: Deserves at least one upvote though ;-)

Comment: oh... a serious answer, way to ruin the fun!

Comment: Well, I don't know Borlace's motivation behind it; any of the other answers here could very well be the reason he had it overflow right :)

Comment: Also, I din't know there was [voting for choosing the site name](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/04/help-name-our-website.html). Interesting.

Comment: @Lazer It's surprising/impressive how much of the site is the result of community decisions and voting

Comment: @Michael Mrozek: yes, surprising and impressive.

Answer (score 9):

It actually overflows to the left; the picture is taken from behind.

Comment: Then why does it overflow to the left?

Comment: @Juan That's an *entirely* different issue. Please do not add new questions as comments or answers; instead use the "Ask Question" link on the top right of this page. See the [FAQ](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq) for details.

Answer (score 7):

Everything flows to the right (in this universe)

[image]

Comment: What's in the (apparently funny) picture?

Comment: @mmyers If you sort the answers by newest, the bottom four posts seem to topple over to the right side. The snapshot was taken before any comments were introduced.

Answer (score 7):

Because the stack doesn't want to overflow to the wrong.

Answer (score 7):

It's a slinky **ending** in the box.

[slinky http://img251.imageshack.us/img251/6549/cljnx.png](http://img251.imageshack.us/img251/6549/cljnx.png)

Comment: ha ha +1 for learning me it's called a slinky in english

Comment: @DrDro what is it called where you're from?

Comment: Literally translated I used to call it: "you know that thing with fluo rainbow colors that goes down the stairs". But you made me check and it appears it's also called a slinky here in france...

Comment: also, it should be "teaching me" @DrDro

Comment: This actually makes more sense since the coloration indicates energy (gray being least active since it has come to a stop, orange being most active)

Answer (score 4):

Isn't it falling forwards, but the image is captured from the side?

Answer (score 3):

Because it was hit by an invisible pink unicorn that came running from the right

Comment: Wouldn't that be "from the left"?

Comment: No, "from the right", then the container moves "to the left" and the contents fall "to the right"

Comment: Maybe if it was a very tiny unicorn. Or a very tall stack.

Comment: It *is* really tiny actually

Comment: Do invisible pink unicorns have colorless green dreams?

Answer (score 2):

"That's what *she* said!"

*...(someone had to say it)*

Answer (score 1):

Because it's on the left side of the logo.

Answer (score 1):

Because the Earth is spinning counterclockwise.

Answer (score 1):

Because the word "stack" has 5 letters (just like "right").

Answer (score 1):

Because programming is art and uses the right side of the brain.

Answer (score 1):

Because we're right!

Answer (score 1):

I hear in the southern hemisphere it flows left.

Comment: Oh?  __I__ always heard that in the __northern__ hemisphere it flowed left.