# Why are tags marked as fun sometimes closed as not constructive?

Tags: discussion, tags, closed-questions, meta

Maybe I missed something important, but I don't really understand why [several](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54580/why-does-the-stack-overflow-logo-lean-to-the-right) [posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72674/celebrating-christmas-on-stack-overflow) [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42919/my-calm-rational-assessment-of-the-global-rep-recalc) marked as fun have been closed as not constructive.

Doesn't "fun" in a sense imply not being constructive? So then why are the majority of fun posts not marked as closed? This seems like an all or nothing situation for me - Either all fun tags are considered not constructive so that they need to be closed, or there truly is a "constructive fun question". Then what defines a "constructive fun question"?

Or were the mentioned posts closed because they simply weren't fun enough? Maybe I'm reading into this too much.

Comment: Because marking something as [meta-tag:fun] is not an excuse to post it in the first place.

Comment: See: [Is fun allowed in MSO?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156977/172431)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are closed because they are not constructive. Adding the tag `fun` does not shield them from being closed.

Regarding why *all* questions tagged fun are not closed: many of these are old questions, asked before more well defined guidelines were worked out for SE sites. Consequently, most of them are subject to historical locks.

On the other hand, some questions are fun, yet also provide a platform for interesting and valuable information/discussion relevant to Stack Overflow or Meta Stack Overflow. A good example is the Many Memes of Meta question, which is ostensibly "fun", yet also clarifies several obscure tropes around here that might leave a newcomer bewildered.